# What is the meaning of " elle ta donné son boule"

Tags: grammaire, usage

-- I understand the literal translation, but wonder if it means something else in the familiar

Comment: Please, give some context.

Comment: elle couché avec toi makes more sense in cont4ext: "Ta donné ton cœur et elle ta donné son boule"

Answer (score 8):

"Boule" in this case is a familiar way of saying ass.
The correct way to write that is :

> Elle **t'a** donné son boule

Meaning more or less :

> Elle a couché avec toi

Comment: That makes sense!  Thank you.

Comment: Sorry, but though I'm French, I never heard that "boule" could mean "ass". Can you quote some examples?

Comment: Same commentary as BBBreiz : never heard...

Comment: What? oO you never heard that? It's impossible if you're french! Just a song to remind you : https://open.spotify.com/track/1GgrYO98uauyu0W62uyqfI?si=Ed9S5hmvQQuv8e69o-364A

Comment: To clarify: **ass** in this context is US English for **arse** in British English. It does not mean the animal.

Comment: C'est une expression "de jeunes". Il y a quelques années (quand j'étais moi-même moins vieux) on disait de façon plus vulgaire : *Elle a payé son cul*.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, *boule* in mistake-riddled *elle ta donné son boule* might refer to furniture made by 17th-century cabinet-maker André-Charles Boulle, commonly known as *boulle*, singular *un boulle*.

[https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Musée_du_Louvre_-_Département_des_Objets_d%27art_-_Salle_34_-2.JPG](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/ee/Mus%C3%A9e_du_Louvre_-_D%C3%A9partement_des_Objets_d%27art_-_Salle_34_-2.JPG)

Comment: If it was the case, there must be capital letter and 2 **l**: “Boulle”.

Comment: @Toto Boulle's pieces are spelt with a small b: un boulle, des boulle.

Comment: Absolument pas, on écrit  un objet **B**oulle, [une marquetterie **B**oulle](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marqueterie_par_d%C3%A9coupe_superpos%C3%A9e)

Comment: @Toto  Ce n'est pas ce que dit le Robert, avec un exemple de Mauriac : "les grandes consoles de faux boulle", et "avoir un boulle".

Comment: Peut-être dans l'expession « un boulle », mais je n'ai jamais vu « Avoir un boulle », on dit plutôt « Avoir un meuble Boulle ». Voir : https://www.art-et-antiques.com/andre-charles-boulle-article-5-7.html

Comment: Humor ? It is certainly not this meaning...