# Shake that ass = secouez ce cul?

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

How would you say ***shake that ass*** as in ***shaking your ass to the music*** in french? Would ***secouez ce cul*** be adequate?

Comment: « Bouge ton cul »

Comment: I thought about that as well but doesn't it mean "hurry up"? @Personne

Answer (score 5):

*Cul* isn't a good choice in that context, being too dismissive.

I'd suggest something like:

> *Allez, remue-toi !*

> *Bouge ton corps !*

> *Trémousse ton [popotin](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/popotin) !* (a little childish and/or jocular)

> *Secoue tes fesses !* (Thanks @LaurentS)

Younger generation might use [*boule*](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/41406/what-is-the-meaning-of-elle-ta-donn%C3%A9-son-boule/41407#41407) for ass and say:

> [Bouge ton boule !](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLF2CP7LemE)

or even

> [*Move* ton boule !](https://l-hit.com/fr/104880)

I guess some people downvoted me for suggesting that !

Comment: "Bouge ton corps" n'est pas idiomatique, ne correspond à rien en français sans un contexte qui ne sera que très rare. One trouve pas "bouge ton corps" dans Google, il n'y a rien.

Comment: @LPH Tu dois avoir des problèmes de clavier ou de réseau. Google trouve d'innombrables "bouge ton corps", en particulier dans des chansons ou des vidéos où l'expression incite à danser.

Comment: That's right, I meant Google ngrams (notjhing from Google ngrams). It is found in various contexts, as you say, but not music and the translation for it is "move your body", which has to do with health for the most part (there is no vulgarity about it). https://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/traduction/bouge+ton+corps.html

Comment: @LPH *Bouge ton corps* is definitely found by Google Ngrams and the 2019 corpus, first occurrences from 1978. There are various songs named or containing *bouge ton corps*. This expression has been used to translate "shake you booty" which precisely means "shake your ass" (Gala about Céline Dion: "Shake your booty, yeahhhh!" ("Bouge ton corps !") s'enflamme la chanteuse en tapant dans ses mains, et en dansant, provoquant l'hilarité de son assistante.)

Comment: L'expresssion « Trémousser son popotin » est connotée sexuellement.

Comment: @Fólkvangr Ni plus ni moins que *shake that ass*. https://yzgeneration.com/shake-that-ass-by-harley-dog/

Comment: Google renvoie des *références pornographiques* en recherchant l'expression « trémousser ses fesses ».

Comment: @Fólkvangr C'est bien possible, mais il ne me semble pas que j'ai proposé cette expression. Tu dois te mélanger les pinceaux.

Comment: Dans un contexte musical, pour éviter le mot cul « Balance tes fesses en rythme » ou « secoue bien tes fesses » pourrait convenir selon la musique entendue.

Comment: J'aurait tendance a dire que juste dire "Trémousse-toi" (qui entre deux adultes peut facilement sous entendre que l'ont parle des hanches, donc fesses en même temps) serait un usage plus adulte a "Trémousse".

Comment: Les mots peuvent être remplacés par des synonymes mais la phrase *est structurée par rapport* au verbe. L'expression « trémousser ses fesses » est une collocation à connotation sexuelle. Enfin, il s'agit d'un emploi fautif puisque le sens approprié ([c.f. TLFi B.](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/tr%C3%A9mousser)) correspond par analogie au verbe pronominal.

Comment: Sans compter que votre affirmation sur l'usage réservé du mot « popotin » au registre enfantin est fausse puisque celle-ci apparaît également dans un contexte sexuel ([«Merde! Ce qu'elles sont moches», soupire l'aspirant. «Eh! dit l'autre, il y a de quoi faire: vise le popotin de la brune»](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/popotin)).

Comment: @SxEequals10nminus2n Je n'ai pas écrit qu'il était "réservé à ce registre, j'ai écrit (enfantin / humoristique), où la barre signifie "et/ou". D'autre part, il est ridicule de penser qu'il existe des synonymes du mot *cul* dont on ne pourrais trouver aucune utilisation dans un contexte sexuel. Est-ce que *shake that ass* est irréprochable à ce sujet ? Bien sûr que non.

Comment: Franchement, "trémousser le popotin" est sans doute parmi les manières les moins "sexy" de désigner ça... A propos de la réponse, quand je dois décrire le twerk, j'emploie précisément le terme "secouer", soit avec "le cul", soit avec "les fesses" (moins vulgaire quand-même)

Comment: @LaurentS. Oui, *trémousse ton popotin !* n'a pas du tout la prétention d'être sexy. Comme je l'ai écrit, c'est plutôt une façon humoristique de le dire. On trouve pas mal de *Secoue tes fesses !*, spécialement pour traduire *shake your booty* comme le *bouge ton corps* de Céline Dion cité plus haut. Je vais le rajouter, merci.

Answer (score 0):

(En complément de la réponse de Jlliagre)

Dans un contexte musical, pour danser, on peut aussi dire

> Allez, on remue les fesses

> Allez, on bouge les hanches

On utilise aussi l'expression

> Se bouger le cul

Mais plutôt pour signifier qu'il faut se mettre en travail

(I y a une variante, mais que je préfère ne pas donner ici !)

Answer (score -2):

"Secouer" does not correspond to idiomatic French in that context. A verb that would belong to that context is "tortiller". However there is not really in French the counterpart of such statemments as addressed to someone viva voce. A somewhat modified form would do; here is one.

- Allez, tortille du/le/ton/ce cul (*as spoken to somebody as an interjection*)
- Allez, tortillez du/le/vos/ces cul (                             "                                 )

It is certainly not something common in French literature as it is not found in Google books. The expression is found in 1690 ([TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/tortiller)).

- 1640 tortiller des fesses (Oudin Curiositez); 1690 tortiller du cul (Fur.)

Comment: *Tortiller du cul* is dismissve so unsuitable to the OP context.

Comment: @jlliagre OALD, ass (North Am E, taboo, slang) = ARSE. Do you think the resulting terms "shake that ass" to be dignified?

Comment: Ce n'est pas tant *cul* que *tortiller* qui ne va pas.

Comment: No native speaker but I think that tortiller du/le cul does not convey shake the ass. https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/tortiller#fr https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pas_besoin_de_tortiller_du_cul_pour_chier_droit

Comment: @Dimitris I agree that it is rather weak if taken to the letter of  the usual meaning.

Comment: @Dimitris Yes. *tortiller du cul* mostly means either "to hesitate, to be embarrassed" or "to dance a ridiculous or miserable way", nothing that match the OP expectations.

Comment: @Dimitris all of that is more or less the same thing
Tortiller des hanches, des fesses, de la croupe [Why not « du cul » ? You can bet that one is part of the choices.]. Se déplacer avec un déhanchement exagéré. 
(Il n')y a pas à tortiller (pop., fam.). Il n'y a pas à hésiter.  Y a pas à tortiller du cul (pour chier droit) (vulg.).

Comment: L'expression « Allez, tortille ton cul ! » est connotée sexuellement.

Comment: @Fólkvangr Selon le contexte, mais dans le contexte de la danse moderne, l'idée seule de tortiller aura cours; cependant les termes eux-mêmes sont des termes de dénigrement.